# Disable/enable device through a macro

Tags: windows, windows-10, macros

So, the source of this question comes from getting a laptop with a wacom pen.  I really like the art apps there are in the Windows store, but most don't have an option to disable touch when using a pen.  Is it possible to bind toggling the HID compliant touch screen on and off to a macro so I don't have to go into device manager every time I want to draw?

Answer (score 0):

You could use powershell to enable/disable devices:

> deviceName = Read-Host -Prompt ‘Please enter the Name of the Device to
>   Disable’; Get-Device | Where-Object -Property Name -Like $deviceName |
>   Disable-Device

Depending on how the device reports itself it might get a bit more complicated - I recommend reading the guide here:

[enter link description here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction/)